# ANTLR generating invalid java exceptions throws code

Tags: java, antlr3, antlrworks

I've been using ANTLRwork 1.5 these days, together with antlr runtime 3.5. Here is a weird thing i found: 
Antlr is generating this kind of java code for me:

```
public final BLABLABLAParser.addExpression_return addExpression() throws {
    blablabla...
}
```

notice that this function throws nothing, and this is invalid in java. So I need to correct these mistakes manually.

Anyone knows why?

here is the sample grammar, it's directly taken from the book *Language implementation patterns*.

```
// START: header
// START: header
grammar Cymbol; // my grammar is called Cymbol
options {
output = AST;
ASTLabelType = CommonTree;
}

tokens{
METHOD_DECL;
ARG_DECL;
BLOCK;
VAR_DECL;
CALL;
ELIST;
EXPR;
}
// define a SymbolTable field in generated parser

compilationUnit // pass symbol table to start rule
:   (methodDeclaration | varDeclaration)+ // recognize at least one variable declaration
;
// END: header

methodDeclaration 
:   type ID '(' formalParameters? ')' block
    -> ^(METHOD_DECL type ID formalParameters? block)
;

formalParameters
:   type ID (',' type ID)* -> ^(ARG_DECL type ID)+
;

// START: type   
type
:   'float' 
|   'int' 
|   'void'  
;
// END: type   

block   :   '{' statement* '}' -> ^(BLOCK statement*)
;

// START: decl
varDeclaration
:   type ID ('=' expression)? ';' -> ^(VAR_DECL type ID expression?)// E.g., "int i = 2;", "int i;"
;
// END: decl

statement
:   block
|   varDeclaration
|   'return' expression? ';' -> ^('return' expression?)
|   postfixExpression
    (
        '=' expression -> ^('=' postfixExpression expression)
        | -> ^(EXPR postfixExpression)
    ) ';'
;



 expressionList
:   expression(',' expression)* -> ^(ELIST expression+)
| -> ELIST
;

expression
:   addExpression -> ^(EXPR addExpression)
;
addExpression
:   postfixExpression('+'^ postfixExpression)*
;
postfixExpression
:   primary (lp='('^ expressionList ')'! {$lp.setType(CALL);})*
;
// START: primary
primary
:   ID // reference variable in an expression
|   INT
|   '(' expression ')' -> expression
;
// END: primary

// LEXER RULES

ID  :   LETTER (LETTER | '0'..'9')*
    ;

fragment
LETTER  :   ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
     ;

INT :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

WS  :   (' '|'\r'|'\t'|'\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

SL_COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\r'|'\n')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

Comment: You probably have an invalid grammar. Can you post your grammar that produces this invalid code?

Comment: Above is the posted grammar. It's almost the same as the grammar from the book <<Language implementation patterns>>

Comment: I've tried to use antlrworks 1.4.2, and this bug is gone. I presume this is a bug for antlrworks 1.5

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** This is a bug in ANTLRWorks 1.5 that has already been fixed for the next release.
[#5: ANTLRworks fails to generate proper Java Code](https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/issues/5)

I used the exact configuration you described above, with a copy/pasted grammar. The signature generated for the rule you mention was the following:

```
// $ANTLR start "addExpression"
// C:\\dev\\Cymbol.g:72:1: addExpression : postfixExpression ( '+' ^ postfixExpression )* ;
public final CymbolParser.addExpression_return addExpression() throws RecognitionException {
```

Can you post the first line of the generated file? It should start with `// $ANTLR 3.5` like the following:

```
// $ANTLR 3.5 C:\\dev\\Cymbol.g 2013-02-13 09:55:44
```